# how to import new products or update existing stock from csv file

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product, csv, grouped-products, simple-product

I've three types of products in my store. Each Grouped product holds a simple product and a configurable product and configurable product in grouped product hold three simple products. Now I want to update the existing stock or import new products from CSV with images please guide me any simple solution to do this in Magento.

Answer (score 2):

Did you look for Magmi ?

http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

> This project is an attempt to provide a product importer for magento
>   that can handle several thousands of products at a reasonable pace
>   compared to magento dataflow. it may evolve to a dataflow alternative
>   as new features are implemented.

Comment: i have download it but i don't know how to import new product with it

Comment: try this http://www.bestresponsemedia.co.uk/how-to-install-and-use-magmi-for-magento/